# Flatten nested JSON using fluentd

Tags: json, logging, fluentd

I have a program that writes structured logs, and the following example applies:

```json
{
    "time": "time_val",
    "log": "{
        \"field1\": \"value1\",
        \"field2\": \"value2\",
        \"field3\": \"{
            \"nested_field1\": \"value1\",
            \"nested_field2\": \"value2\",
            \"nested_field3\": \"value3\"
        }\"
    }"
}
```

I am using fluentd to tail the output of the container, and parse JSON messages, however, I would like to parse the nested structured logs, so they are flattened in the original message. For the example, I would want fluentd to eventually consider the message as:

```json
{
    "time": "time_val",
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "nested_field1": "value1",
    "nested_field2": "value2",
    "nested_field3": "value3"
}
```

Is this something that can be done using fluentd configuration? Changing the original program behavior is not an option in my case.

Comment: BTW, that JSON is not valid. The quotes in the nested JSON should be escaped. Check with https://www.jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Please take a look at this example: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#remove_key_name_field

Comment: The update JSON is invalid. Please validate it and update accordingly.

Comment: The double-nested JSON is still not valid. See my updated answer for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser) filter plugin with its [key_name](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#key_name), [reserve_data](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#reserve_data), and [remove_key_name_field](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#remove_key_name_field).

Example:

```xml
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name field3
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

---

Here is the **complete working example** after making your JSON valid i.e.:

```json
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"{\"nested_field1\":\"value1\",\"nested_field2\":\"value2\",\"nested_field3\":\"value3\"}"}
```

**fluent-flatten-json.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type forward
</source>

<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name field3
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Run `fluentd`:

```bash
fluentd -c ./fluent-flatten-json.conf
```

From another terminal, run `fluent-cat` with input JSON:

```bash
fluent-cat test <<< '{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"{\"nested_field1\":\"value1\",\"nested_field2\":\"value2\",\"nested_field3\":\"value3\"}"}'
```

Output in `fluentd` logs:

```json
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","nested_field1":"value1","nested_field2":"value2","nested_field3":"value3"}
```

Formatted output:

```json
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "nested_field1": "value1",
  "nested_field2": "value2",
  "nested_field3": "value3"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

For a double-nested valid raw escaped JSON:

```json
{"time":"time_val","log":"{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"{\\\"nested_field1\\\":\\\"nested_value1\\\",\\\"nested_field2\\\":\\\"nested_value2\\\",\\\"nested_field3\\\":\\\"nested_value3\\\"}\"}"}
```

The double-nested JSON in the question is not valid. I had to recreate it. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jhMheo9Pe).

The following should work:

```xml
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name field3
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my original question was not correct, because I didn't take into account that the input is already coming in the format of {"log": ... } so I need a double nesting solution. I have updated the question, hoping you can help again.

Comment: Thanks Azeem, I also tried this approach and it worked for me, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do this? If I choose this filtering, it seems like each log line goes through two filtering operations, which I guess, less performant?

Comment: @Ohad: Sure, no problem. Figuring out valid JSON took some time. Anyways, IMO, it's the straightforward approach. You can experiment with `record_transformer`/`record_modifier` or `jq` filters or you can resort to using Ruby directly. I wouldn't worry about it until it really becomes a performance issue. Apart from that, fluentd internally uses [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/index.html). You might want to [try it online](https://msgpack.org/index.html#json-to-msgpack) with your actual JSON event and observe its comparative msgpack size.